# How do I slice a 3D object at runtime in Unity?

Tags: unity, c#

I'm specifically looking for some sort of algorithm or way that can "cut" a 3 dimensional mesh with some other game object. How would I implement this?

Comment: https://youtu.be/3g5_8sE18tQ

Comment: I know this is not an answer, but i found [some code](https://github.com/BLINDED-AM-ME/UnityAssets) that you might find helpful. If someone understands how this works, *please* post an answer

Comment: Is it safe to assume thar you started by [searching for existing answers on the topic of cutting meshes](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/search?q=cut+mesh)? What techniques that you've researched so far look promising to.you, and how have you tried implementing them based on your research? Where have you gotten stuck in that process? The more specific you can be, the faster you'll tend to get answers, and the deeper and better-targeted they'll be to the details you need.